# Проблема со сменой текста(setText) через таймер

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text

Текст не меняется,событие(mTimerTask) вызывается.Также подскажите ,пожалуйста,как сделать ежесекундную проверку таймера?(Для того,чтобы если таймер запущен,то кнопка была выключена)Заранее спасибо!
Вот код:

```
public class game extends Activity {
ImageButton imageButton5;
TextView textView3;
TextView textView4;
TextView textview5;
Timer timer;
TimerTask mTimerTask;
TimerTask OutputResultats;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
}

public void OutputResultats(View view) {
    timer = new Timer();
    mTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    imageButton5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    if (timer != null) {

        timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 5000);
    } else {
        imageButton5.setEnabled(false);
    }

}

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        int cS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        textView3.setText("Ваш результат:" + pS);
        textView4.setText("Результат компьютера:" + cS);
        timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 5000);
        if (pS < cS) {
            textview5.setText("Победил компьютер!Повезёт в следующий раз!");
        } else {
            textview5.setText("Вы выиграли!Поздравляю!");
        }
        if (pS == cS) {
            textview5.setText("Победила дружба;)");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Работать с разметкой можно только в главном (UI) потоке. Следовательно, вам надо делать так:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        final int pS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        final int cS = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 5000);

        //обновляем разметку в основном потоке
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
           @Override
           public void run() {
                   textView3.setText("Ваш результат:" + pS);
                   textView4.setText("Результат компьютера:" + cS);
                   if (pS < cS) {
                       textview5.setText("Победил компьютер!Повезёт в следующий раз!");
                   } else {
                       textview5.setText("Вы выиграли!Поздравляю!");
                   }
                   if (pS == cS) {
                       textview5.setText("Победила дружба;)");
                   }
           }});
    }
}
```

**UPD_0:**

И да, как верно отметили в ответе к другому вашему вопросу вам надо `setContentView(R.layout.game);` вызывать **до** поиска элементов разметки, т.к. до вызова этого метода разметки ещё нет и вашим `TextView` присваивается `null`

Comment: Не работает,ругается на строку,где меняется текст.Вот мой код:

Comment: @Vladimir51, как именно ругается? Какая ошибка? Думаю, вам может помочь объявление полей `TextView` финальными, т.е. `final TextView textView3;`

Comment: @Vladimir51, смотрите обновлённый ответ.